# Campaign ID and Audience ID in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign

Where can I find the campaign ID and audience ID in SFMC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ask it opening a ticket to Support in order to create for you a custom data view with that information. The way Campaigns work in SFMC is totally different as in Sales Cloud.